# RestEasy ClientRequest followRedirect behaviour on POST

Tags: resteasy

To my knowledge the correct way, in a restful sense, to handle creation of a new resource is to POST the request and then redirect the client to the result via header location field.

It seems ClientRequest does not support this. I cannot get the ClientRequest to automatically follow the see other (303) redirect after a post. When a PostMethod is created by the RestEasy client framework followRedirect is set to false ignoring the followRedirect set on the ClientRequest.

Is there another way?

Comment: I am assuming a PostProcessInterceptor is the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has been specifically implemented to not automatically follow redirects.